# Сборка проекта

Tags: java, netbeans

Скажите, пожалуйста,как мне правильно собрать проект. у меня есть один файл и в методе main  у меня вызывается метод, которому нужно указывать путь. как мне поступить?

Answer (score 3):

Если кратко, то ответ [@vinger4](/users/14024/vinger4)
Если развернуто:
Смотря, что Вы конкретно имеете ввиду под сборкой ;-)
Нет, не подумаете я прекрасно понимаю, что такое сборка проекта, делаю это каждую пятницу))...
Если Вы хотите просто скомпилировать проект, то могу посоветовать Вам статью:
http://habrahabr.ru/post/125210/
Другой момент, именно сборка, это значит, что Вы хотите не просто скомпилировать, а именно "собрать" проект. Т.е. есть куча частей из которых этот проект состоит, Вы хотите присвоить некоторую версию и пр.
В интернетах Вы можете наткнуться на на сравнение каких-то ant и maven, или что-то такое. Не буду вдаваться в подробности, Вам нужен maven:
http://maven.apache.org/
Отличная шутковина. Сначала не очень понятная, но потом очень необходимая, начать стоит с
http://habrahabr.ru/post/77382/
http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/ru/edu/j-mavenv2/
Был еще очень доступный мануал, по которому учился я но он канул в Лету(
Прочитайте лишним явно не будет, скорее всего после этого Вы сами ответите на свой вопрос.

Answer (score 0):

предлагаю сразу использовать maven - там можно будет прописать этот параметр в файле pom.xml